# Showing Cauchy-problem is defined

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I want to show that if $p>1$ the solution of $x'=x^{p} \quad ,x(0)=a>0 \quad$ is not defined for all $t\geq 0$.

I'm not sure on this one, am I supposed to find the solution $x$ and show that it is not continous? Or is there a theoreom that I can apply on $f(t,x)=x^{p}$ for this?

Comment: You can write down the solution (bring $x^p$ to the other side and integrate). Then you can check that the solution explodes in finite time.

Comment: I get the solution $x(t)=\left((1-p)t+a^{1-p}\right)^{\frac{1}{1-p}}$. I don't see what you mean with that it explodes?

Comment: If $p>1$ then at time $t=a^{1-p}/(p-1)$ your function has a pole, i.e. it explodes (goes to infinity).

Answer (score 1):

Dividing by $x^p$, the differential equation writes $x'(t) x(t)^{-p} = 1$, which can be integrated over $[0,t]$ as follows:
$$
\frac{x(t)^{1-p}}{1-p} - \frac{a^{1-p}}{1-p} = t - 0 \, .
$$
The value of $x(t)$ can be retrieved as long as $(1-p) t + a^{1-p}\neq 0$, i.e. $$0\leq t < \frac{a^{1-p}}{p-1}\, .$$
If this condition is satisfied, then
$$
x (t) = \left((1-p)t + a^{1-p} \right)^\frac{1}{1-p} .
$$

Comment: Yes I obtained this solution, but I can't see how I show that it's not defined for $t\geq 0$ if $p>1$?

Comment: I cant really get a grip of your solution, I've only seen methods where one seperates the differential equation or multiply with a factor of $e^{P(t)}$.

Comment: This is the standard way of solving such [separable ODEs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_variables#Ordinary_differential_equations_.28ODE.29)